# При разворачивании сайта на ModX с хостинга на локалку выдает пустую страницу

Tags: хостинг, modx, localhost, развертывание

Я сделал следующее:

1. Скачал с хостинга. Добавил папку с сайтом в domains open-server'a.
2. Изменил пути в файлах:

   ```
   /config.core.php
   /connectors/config.core.php
   /manager/config.core.php
   config/config.inc.php
   ```

на `D:/progs/open-server/OpenServer/domains/new/core/`
(`new` - папка с сайтом)

3. Добавил базу данных в phpMyAdmin
4. так стала выглядеть конфигурация в `config.inc.php`:

   ```
   $database_type = 'mysql';
   $database_server = 'localhost';
   $database_user = 'root';
   $database_password = '';
   $database_connection_charset = 'utf8';
   $database_connection_method = 'SET CHARACTER SET';
   $dbase = 'new';
   $table_prefix = 'fabrika_';
   $database_dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=new;charset=utf8';
   ```

и т.д.

5. Запустил `new/setup`: https://monosnap.com/file/kxJuh03ZVHsJ9HTqJgRCxUSvBfzGGt
6. вошел в админку, почистил кэш. Поменял во вкладке "контексте" пути сайта на fabrika-msk.xyz и  fabrika-spb.xyz, т.к. мультидомейный проект.
7. Изменил конфигурацию HTTP хоста в файле apach на:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "D:/progs/open-server/OpenServer/domains/new"
      ServerName fabrika-spb.xyz
      ServerAlias www.fabrika-spb.xyz
      ErrorLog "D:/progs/open-server/OpenServer/domains/new/error.log"
      CustomLog "D:/progs/open-server/OpenServer/domains/new/access.log" common
   </VirtualHost>

   <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "D:/progs/open-server/OpenServer/domains/new"
      ServerName fabrika-msk.xyz
      ServerAlias www.fabrika-msk.xyz
      ErrorLog "D:/progs/open-server/OpenServer/domains/new/error.log"
      CustomLog "D:/progs/open-server/OpenServer/domains/new/access.log" common
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
8. еще раз слил кэш и при запуске выдает пустую страницу(без ошибок).

Comment: Подозреваю, что может быть ошибка с одним из плагинов, например *phx*. Ошибку он скорее всего не выводит на экран, так как если предположить что локально в установках PHP ошибки выводятся на экран, то в конфигурации MODx эти значения переписываются и их нужно изменить.

Comment: `$database_password = '';` - это ты удалил или так и есть пустой пароль?

Comment: Вполне вероятно,что именно в $database_password = ''; и есть проблема, т.к. причиной белой страницы на сайте может быть неправильное подключение к БД